# Para exibir o dia da semana de qualquer data nos últimos 1.000 anos

Tags: sql, oracle

Usei este comando

```
select to_char(to_date('18-apr-1972','dd-mon-yyyy'),'day') day from DUAL;
```

mas deu erro na execução:

```
ORA-01841: ano (completo) deve estar entre -4713 e +9999 e não pode ser zero
01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
*Cause:    Illegal year entered
*Action:   Input year in the specified range
```

Alguém poderia me mostrar outra forma? Uso o Oracle.

Comment: Só lembrando que, em qualquer sistema, a base de contagem começa em 01-01-1970. Pelo menos os microssegundos começaram a partir dessa data.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino errado. Isso é o POSIX time, em boa parte dos DBs se usa o Proleptic Gregorian Day, que começa em 4714 BC (indicado por -4713, pq nao tem ano zero) - e mesmo assim, em posix você pode usar numeros negativos para datas anteriores a 1970. Além disso, DBs que usam Posix não costumarm adotar microssegundos na armazenagem, por padrão. O campo é variante de INT normalmente.

Comment: @Bacco Boa! Uma que não sabia. Por essa informação nem apagarei meu comentário para constar.

Comment: @WilliamAparecidoBrandino se resolver apagar, basta depois sinalizar o meu como obsoleto (na bandeirinha ao lado dele), que a moderação limpa depois. Se quiser mais detalhes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proleptic_Gregorian_calendar - normalmente é armazenado como Float nos DBs, sendo que a fração é o tempo, e o inteiro os dias. Exemplo: Sétimo ano, ao meio dia, fica `7.5`. Em Posix já são inteiros, sendo o número de segundos corridos desde a data que vc mencionou (ou anterior a ela se for número negativo) e toma por base sempre 86400 segundos todos os dias (sem _leap_).

Answer (score 1):

Assim funciona:

```
select to_char(to_date('18-04-1972','dd-MM-yyyy'),'day') day from DUAL;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigada!!!